# React-scripts Dependency Issue After Running npm audit fix --force

Tags: reactjs, npm, frontend

I'm encountering an issue with npm audit fix --force in my React project. After running the command, I receive the following message:

> There might be a problem with the project dependency tree. It is likely
> not a bug in Create React App, but something you need to fix locally.
>
> The react-scripts package provided by Create React App requires a
> dependency:
>
> "babel-jest": "^24.9.0"
>
> Don't try to install it manually: your package manager does it
> automatically. However, a different version of babel-jest was detected
> higher up in the tree:
>
> /home/michal/node_modules/babel-jest (version: 29.6.2)

Manually installing incompatible versions is known to cause
hard-to-debug issues. I've tried deleting package-lock.json,
node_modules, and rerunning npm install as suggested, but the problem
persists. Here are the steps I've taken:

1. Deleted package-lock.json.
2. Deleted node_modules.
3. Ran npm install.

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: You shouldn't have a `node_modules` directory in your home directory `/home/michal` at all. Try renaming that to (to e.g. `/home/michal/odd_node_modules`) begin with.